# Creating MySQL relationships with foreign keys and alter statements

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-key-relationship

I will try to be specific because I feel my understanding of the subject isn't quite precise as well. My problem is understanding how to create relations between tables with foreign keys which I add with alter statements. I have these tables.

```
CREATE TABLE article (
    content TEXT NOT NULL,
    published_on DATE NOT NULL,
    created_on DATE NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE category(
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    date_created DATE NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE user(
    income FLOAT(30, 30) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    picture_url TEXT NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE tag(
    description VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    second_priority FLOAT(30, 30) NOT NULL,
);
```

To which I have to make there relationships:

```
Tag has a one to one connection to Category
Category has a many to one connection to User
User has a one to many connection to Article
```

And to do that I use there statements:

```
ALTER TABLE tag ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (tag_id) REFERENCES category (category_id);
ALTER TABLE category ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (user_id);
ALTER TABLE user ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES article (user_id);
```

My problem is that the third one fails. When I switch the places of article and user the constraint passes. After a bit of digging and experimenting I found out that I can't constraint two keys from which one is either UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY and the other one just NOT NULL. So far I don't know how to continue, can someone please enlighten me as to how to create a one to one, many to one, one to many and a many to many relationship between these tables because I am kinda lost and everything in my head is a mess.

FULL STUFF:

```
CREATE DATABASE exam_database;
USE exam_database;
CREATE TABLE article (
    content TEXT NOT NULL,
    published_on DATE NOT NULL,
    created_on DATE NOT NULL,
    user_id INT(30) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE category(
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    date_created DATE NOT NULL,
    category_id INT(30) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
    user_id INT(30) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE user(
    income FLOAT(30, 30) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    picture_url TEXT NOT NULL,
    user_id INT(30) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE tag(
    description VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    second_priority FLOAT(30, 30) NOT NULL,
    tag_id INT(30) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE
);

ALTER TABLE tag ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (tag_id) REFERENCES category (category_id);
ALTER TABLE category ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (user_id);
ALTER TABLE user ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES article (user_id);
```

Comment: Paste Your full (with keys) create statement for this tables...

Comment: @AnR here you go, the full code

Comment: If `user_id` is the PK of your `user` table (as one would expect), then surely `article.user_id` references that and not the other way around|?

Comment: @eggyal I think you are right, can you still explain to me how I'd go about to create one to one, one to many and a many to many in the same fashion?

Comment: @EcoGiko You seem to have figured out 1:1 and 1:∞. For ∞:∞ you create one more table with 2 fields to hold the relations (e.g. tag_category `(tag_id,category_id)`.

Comment: @Vatev I am not sure I have figured out anything. Here is the dpaste of my understanding of the relationships - https://dpaste.de/yJFg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Your structure has some errors:
Missing PK, Why using INT(30)? etc...
Your DB should looks like:

```
CREATE DATABASE exam_database;
USE exam_database;
CREATE TABLE article (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    content TEXT NOT NULL,
    published_on DATE NOT NULL,
    created_on DATE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE category(
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    date_created DATE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE user (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE    ,
    income FLOAT(30, 30) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    picture_url TEXT NOT NULL

);

CREATE TABLE tag (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
    category_id INT NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    second_priority FLOAT(30, 30) NOT NULL

);
```

Second Your FKs should look like:

```
ALTER TABLE tag ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES category (id);
ALTER TABLE category ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (id);
ALTER TABLE article ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES  user (id);
```